# iBatis gives an error: "com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException"

Tags: database, ibatis

I am making cache for iBatis. I am using `cache-model` with `flushInterval`, `flushOnExecute` lines and a `property` named `reference-type`. Then after deploy I get the mentioned error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/end()'. Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: There is no statement named ibatorgenerated_updateByPrimaryKeySelective in this SqlMap.`

Comment: I have a `useStatementNamespaces="true"` setting. [This post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ibatis-user-java/200612.mbox/%3C50CA25BD6EEA954FA592C097399942E318C32EC8@CM1.wis.local%3E) lets me to interesting track. Have to check it out :)

Comment: On `FlushOnExecute` element at the attribute`statement=query_name` I had to use 'naming.query_name' when having namespace 'naming'. Normally namespace usage is not needed all the times but this part needs it. My help was found on the post referred to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `FlushOnExecute` element there was an attribute`statement` set with value 'some_query'. I had to use 'naming.some_query' wbecause I was using namespace 'naming'. Normally namespace usage is not needed all the times but this part needs it.